# Why is there no underflow warning for unsigned type?

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, clang++

Consider the following code:

```
unsigned int n = 0;
unsigned int m = n - 1;              // no warning here?
if (n > -1) {
    std::cout << "n > -1.\n";
} else {
    std::cout << "yes, 0 is not > -1.\n";
}
```

The code above produces a warning on the `if` condition `if (m > -1)` for comparing signed and unsigned integer expressions. I have no contest with that. What bothers me is the first two assignment statements.

```
unsigned int n = 0;
unsigned int m = n - 1;
```

My thinking is that the compiler should have given me a warning on the second assignment because it knows that the variable `n` is unsigned with a value of `0` from the first line and that there was an attempt to subtract from a zero value and assigning it to an unsigned type.

If the next line after the second assignment happened to be different than an `if` statement or something similar, then the concerned code might have slipped through.

Yes, there is a narrowing conversion before the assignment to `m` there and yes the compiler do not complain about it which was also mentioned by Marshall Clow in his C++Now 2017 Lightning Talk (Fighting Compiler Warnings).

```
short s = 3 * 6;
short s = integer * integer;
short s = integer;
```

So, why can't the compiler tell me about the possible underflow in that code?

Compilers:

- Clang 3.7/4.0 (-Wall -Wextra)
- GCC 5.3/7.1.1 (-Wall -Wextra -pedantic)
- Microsoft C/C++ 19.00.23506

Comment: What warning do you expect to get?  The warning you get on the if statement is *comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions* which is not what is happening in `unsigned int m = n - 1;`

Comment: Have you tried with `-Wall` and `-Wextra` options of GCC?

Comment: @Plouff: Yes, I've used -Wall -Wextra with GCC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because `if (n > -1)` can never be false, but `unsigned int m = n - 1;` is an actual legal expression you may have wanted to write. From 5/9 there are a bunch of rules about how to get your signed an unsigned types to have a consistent type, and all of them fail except the final default condition

> Otherwise, both operands shall be converted to the unsigned integer
>   type corresponding to the type of the operand with signed integer
>   type.

Since unsigned arithmetic is well-defined to use modulo operations the entire expression is legal and well defined. They could yet decide to emit a warning but there may be enough legacy code using tricks like this that it would cause too many false positives.

Comment: Is there free static code checkers that would emit warnings for this kind issues?

Comment: "legacy code": it does **not** have to be legacy code, that's a perfectly valid thing to write in new code. On the other hand, using an unsigned type for something other than bigint type of code (where you want wraparound) or a bitfield is usually misguided.